# Can't center layout in isotope

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, jquery-isotope

I am really struggling with this and can't seem to find a solution.

I made a gallery using isotope. The problem is that I can't center the whole ul to the page.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="filters" class="portfolio-filters">
  <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a id="all" href="#" data-filter="*" class="active"><h5>All</h5></a></li>   
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".branding"><h5>Branding</h5></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".design"><h5>Design</h5></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".photography"><h5>Photography</h5></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".videography"><h5>Videography</h5></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".web"><h5>Web</h5></a></li>
          </ul>
</div>

<ul class="ullist">
<div id="Portfolio" class="portfolio"><li class="portfolio-item branding"><div class="mainbox">*** branding ***</div></li>
<li class="portfolio-item branding"><div class="mainbox">*** branding ***</div></li>
<li class="portfolio-item photography"><div class="mainbox">*** photography ***</div></li>
<li class="portfolio-item videography"><div class="mainbox">*** videography ***</div></li>
<li class="portfolio-item web"><div class="mainbox">*** web ***</div></li>
<li class="portfolio-item web"> <div class="mainbox">*** web ***</div> </li>
</div>     
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  var $container = $('#Portfolio');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  });

  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('#filters a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });
});
```

I tried the following method in JS but there were visual problems with the layout.

```
$container.isotope({
    // disable window resizing
    resizable: false,
    fotrows: {
      columnWidth: colW
```

Here you can see a live version of the code: http://codepen.io/mariomez/pen/doJvJz

Comment: It looks centered to me... Define "there were visual problems with the layout".

Comment: Try using css instead,check out answer

Comment: @Jonathan .. The buttons are centered but the whole ul list is on the left.

Comment: css doesn't work at all. Isotope JS overrides any css applied :/

Comment: Your codepen goes to an error page, not your live version

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `ul` in a div like

```
<div id="center_div">
  <ul>
     <!-- your ul content-->
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then center it using css like

```
#center_div {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```